# A question about eclipse extend tool builder programming

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to implement an eclipse plugin to add an shell script as an external tool builder to a project. After the plugin menu is pressed, the eclipse configuration file .project would add  as following. And another configuration file .externalToolBuilders/lstest [Builder].launch would be generated.

```
<buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
        <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
            <dictionary>
                <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
                <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/lstest [Builder].launch</value>
            </dictionary>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Currently, I could add  to .project using the following code. But How could I generate .externalToolBuilders/lstest [Builder].launch ? Thank you very much.

```
org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand command = pDesc.newCommand();
     command.setBuilderName("org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder");
Map args = command.getArguments();
args.put("LaunchConfigHandle", "<project>;/.externalToolBuilders/lstest [Builder].launch");
args = conf.getAttributes();
command.setArguments(args);
org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand command = BuilderUtils.commandFromLaunchConfig(projects[i],conf);
org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand[] commands = pDesc.getBuildSpec();
 org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand[] nc = new ICommand[commands.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(commands, 0, nc, 1, commands.length);
nc[0] = command;
pDesc.setBuildSpec(nc);
projects[i].setDescription(pDesc, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From menu press on "Run/External tools/External tools configurations..." there you can define ant runners, program runners. On the other hand I am not sure you can attach a shell script directly but to call it from ant.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the lstest.launch in the .externalToolBuilders folder. Add the following lines before your codes

```
    ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
ILaunchConfigurationType antType =
launchManager.getLaunchConfigurationType(IExternalToolConstants.ID_PROGRAM_BUILDER_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_TYPE);

ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy = antType.newInstance(BuilderUtils.getBuilderFolder(project, true), "lstest" ); 
workingCopy.setAttribute(IDebugUIConstants.ATTR_LAUNCH_IN_BACKGROUND, false);
workingCopy.setAttribute(IExternalToolConstants.ATTR_LOCATION, "${project_loc}\\YOUR_SHELL_SCRIPT");
workingCopy.setAttribute(....);


ILaunchConfiguration ilc = workingCopy.doSave();
```

[create ANT builder programmatically](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t112003.html)