# Developing an Eclipse plugin that can add an External Builder to a project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**EDIT:**
I was not able to figure out how to make my plugin add an external builder that has the same configuration as a manually added builder. I decided that using Bananeweizen's suggestion of modifying project files directly wasn't maintainable enough. We're giving up for now. We'll have the user manually create the external builder.

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin to act as a GUI for an excellent command line tool one of my colleagues developed. Developers use the plugin to create a bash script that runs the command line tool with certain configurations. Once the bash script has been created, it can be manually added to the Eclipse project as an External Tool Builder (see image below); **automating that step is where I'm having trouble**.

[image: **I can add the bash script manually, but not programatically**]

First, the code that adds the bash script as an External Builder:

```
createBuilderConfigFile();

IProjectDescription desc = project.getDescription();
ICommand newCommand = desc.newCommand();
newCommand.setBuilding(IncrementalProjectBuilder.AUTO_BUILD, false);
newCommand.setBuilding(IncrementalProjectBuilder.INCREMENTAL_BUILD, false);
newCommand.setBuilding(IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD, false);
newCommand.setBuilding(IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD, true);
newCommand.setBuilderName("org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder");
Map<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
arguments.put("LaunchConfigHandle", "<project>/.externalToolBuilders/CodeGen.launch");
newCommand.setArguments(arguments);
List<ICommand> allCommands = new ArrayList<ICommand>();
allCommands.add(newCommand);
for (ICommand command : desc.getBuildSpec()) {
    allCommands.add(command);
}
ICommand[] commandArray = allCommands.toArray(new ICommand[allCommands.size()]);
desc.setBuildSpec(commandArray);
project.setDescription(desc, null);
```

The first line creates a file called `CodeGen.launch`. It's similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282547/a-question-about-eclipse-extend-tool-builder-programming). Then the rest of the code updates the `.project` file in my Eclipse project with code that looks like this:

```
<buildCommand>
  <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
  <arguments>
     <dictionary>
        <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
        <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/CodeGen.launch</value>
     </dictionary>
  </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

It almost works perfectly. When the project is built, the script is run. However, the script updates the source files, which causes the project to be built again if *Project->Build Automatically* is selected from the Eclipse main menu. The re-build causes the script to be run again, and the cycle continues until the user turns off auto-build.

If I open the list of Builders I can see the builder my plugin created (see the image above). If I click *Edit...*, **make no changes**, and then click *OK*, the new builder only gets run for manual builds, not auto-builds. The `.project` file is different now; manually opening and saving the builder definition caused Eclipse to update it. It looks like:

```
<buildCommand>
  <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
  <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
  <arguments>
     <dictionary>
        <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
        <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/CodeGen.launch</value>
     </dictionary>
     <dictionary>
        <key>incclean</key>
        <value>true</value>
     </dictionary>
  </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Notice the new `<triggers>` tag and the new `<dictionary>` value. If you look at my code, you can see the lines where I try to specify which builds the script should be run for. These lines are ignored; I can comment them out and the resulting `.project` file is no different. This is probably due to the fact that "org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder" is a builder that is not configurable. I've confirmed that `newCommand.isConfigurable()` returns false, and the documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_resources_builders.html) suggests that a builder that returns false for `isConfigurable()` will ignore `setBuilding()`. I've searched for an extension point other than "org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder", one that is open for configuration, but I haven't found one yet.

Is there any way for my plugin to define an external builder with the same results as a user who defines the builder manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you could still scan and update the .project file by means of file reading/writing. Afterwards call `iProject.refreshLocal(DEPTH_INFINITE, ...)` on the project that you modified to make Eclipse aware of the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Explicitly writing the contents of the file is my last resort solution (it's what the createBuilderConfigFile() method did before I found that other SO post).

Comment: I think you might be fishing at the wrong place. Have a look at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy.html, which has a setAttribute(...) method, and you want to invoke that as workingCopy.setAttribute(IExternalToolConstants.ATTR_RUN_BUILD_KINDS, "full,incremental,"); I looked at ExternalToolsBuilderTab.performApply() to come to that conclusion.

Comment: Thanks again.I'm currently using workingCopy.setAttribute(...) to configure the .launch file that the external builder references (you can see it's called CodeGen.launch in my case). My .launch file does specify that it should only be run for full and incremental builds. However, this doesn't seem to prevent it from being run for auto-builds. I will, however, take a second look the org.eclipse.debug.core package to see if there's something I've missed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any movement on this question. Although it's not the answer I was looking for, your solution might actually be the only solution. Thanks.